# setState => Dont spread array if empty - React

Tags: reactjs, firebase, redux

```
handleCommentChange = (e) => {
    const commentID = idGenerator();
    this.setState({
        movie: {
            movieId: this.props.match.params.id,
            ...this.props.movie,           
            comments:[
                ...this.props.movie.comments,
                {     
                    commentID: commentID,
                    by:this.props.profile.firstName,                   
                    userID: this.props.auth.uid,
                    createdAt: new Date(),
                    comment: e.target.value               
                }               
            ]
        },


        profile:{
            ...this.props.profile,
            comments:[
                ...this.props.profile.comments,
                {                              
                    movieId: this.props.match.params.id,
                    commentID: commentID,                                             
                    createdAt: new Date(),
                    comment: e.target.value               
                }
            ]                           

        }
    })
}
```

That's code for adding comments, in two firebase collections... Everything works great if "this.props.movie.comments" have items in an array... The problem begins if that array is empty.

How can I skip that spreading function if that array is empty?

Am I doing this in the right way?

Thanks

Comment: It should work if the array is empty as well. Are you sure the props are arrays at all, and not e.g. `null`?

Comment: Actually, I don't... In the constructor, I am spreading ... this.props.movie & this.props.profile, but all that defaults are asigned when user creates an account on other component and same asignments are made when user adds new movie to database... All that data exist in firebase, but arrays are empty... ?

Comment: Alright. What error are you getting?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do it would be a null check I think, since an empty array can still be spread, either in the constructor or in here. You can do it without code duplication by setting a local constant to either the array, or an empty array.

```
const movieComments = this.props.movies ? this.props.movies : [];
this.setState({
    movie: {
        movie: {
        movieId: this.props.match.params.id,
        ...this.props.movie,           
        comments:[
            ...movieComments,
            {     
                commentID: commentID,
                by:this.props.profile.firstName,                   
                userID: this.props.auth.uid,
                createdAt: new Date(),
                comment: e.target.value               
            }               
        ]
    },
    profile:{
        ...this.props.profile,
        comments:[
            ...this.props.profile.comments,
            {                              
                movieId: this.props.match.params.id,
                commentID: commentID,                                             
                createdAt: new Date(),
                comment: e.target.value               
            }
        ]                           

    }
});
```

The same thing is possible for `this.props.profile.comments` in case you have the same behavior there. Generally, I'd make sure that it was always passed either an empty array or a populated array, rather than passing null as a prop.

Answer (score 1):

I opt for this when needed..

```
...(this.props.movie.comments || []),
```